# Velleman exercise 22 sec 4.4 on relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

So I'm going through Velleman's book "how to prove it: a structured approach",
I'm kinda confused about exercise 22 at section 4.4
It goes like this:

*"Suppose that R is a partial order on A,

$B_1$⊆ A, $B_2$⊆ A,
 $x_1$ is the least
upper bound of $B_1$, 
 $x_2$ is the least upper bound of $B_2$.

 Prove that if
$B_1$ ⊆ $B_2$ then {$x_1$,$x_2$}∈ R ."*

Now since I can think of an example when this is not true I suspect I must have gotten something wrong, maybe what an upper bound is?
My example:
 let A={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 132, 264, 420, 2940}
Let R={(x,y) ∈ A × A| x divides y }
then since R is reflexive, transitive and antisimmetric we can conclude that R is a partial order on A.
Now let $B_1$={ 2,3,4 } and $B_2$ = { 2,3,4,5 },
clearly $B_1$ ⊆A , $B_2$ ⊆ A and $B_1$⊆$B_2$.
Now I believe 132 is an upper bound of $B_1$
 that is:
132∈A and   ∀ z if z ∈ $B_1$ then (z,132) ∈ R 
 now let H ={h| h is an upper bound of $B_1$ } it seems to me that 132 is the smallest element of H and I think this is what "least upper bound of $B_1$" means.
Then the same line of reasoning would apply to 420 so I think 420 is the least upper bound of $B_2$
But (132,420) ∉R
I'm probably making the most stupid mistake but could someone point out what I got wrong?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm aware that when the partial order is S= {(x,y) ∈ A × A| x<y or x=y\} then your definition is correct, but from what I understand the definition of upper bound(or all the other terms really)  depends on wich relation we are referring to. So that in my example your definition would not apply. I might be wrong, when I studied these terms in "analisi 1", in italian "minorante" e "maggiorante" were thaught to me as you describe them, but then again in "analisi 1" is implicit that we are referring to a specific relation ( S ). (I'm taking for granted you're italian)

Comment: I agree with you with the fact that there is some "trick" ... It is easy to prove that $x_2$ is an *upper bound* for $B_1$; thus **if** $x_1$ is the l.u.b. of $B_1$ we have (by def) : an upper bound is the least upper bound if it is "less than" any other upper bound. If we stay with it, we have that $132$ and $420$ are **both** upper bounds of $B_1$ but $132$ is **not** the l.u.b. because it is not "comparable" with $420$. Thus, $420$ is the l.u.b. of both $B_1$ and $B_2$, and : $420|420$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Of course! There's my mistake...420 would be an element of H and so H cannot have a smallest element for the reason you wrote... then in my example there is no least upper bound of B1. 
Thank you for your time!